# How can I submit multiple commands to an LSF under one job ID?

Tags: java, jobs, lsf

I have ~3,500 jobs running `Beagle` to submit to an LSF using `bsub`. As the server I am using operates on a fair-share queuing system, I'm reluctant to have my queuing priority drop through the floor by running each job individually.

As such, I have attempted to run through my commands using a for loop within a single `bsub` command...

```
cbsub -G cichlid -e beagle_e_%J -o beagle_o_%J
-R'select[mem>10000] rusage[mem=10000]' -M10000 -n 8 -q long sh -c
'for sc in {014444451..014448004}; do
/nfs/users/nfs_m/mm21/programs/jre1.7.0_71/bin/java -Xmx10000m -jar
/nfs/users/nfs_m/mm21/programs/beagle4.0/beagle.r1398.jar
gl=Passed_filtered_snps_round2_per_scaff/NW_${sc}_2.vcf nthreads=8
ibd=true ibdtrim=200 phase-its=8 impute-its=8
out=Passed_filtered_snps_round2_per_scaff/beagle_output_NW_${sc};done'
```

...but I just receive the error message:

> syntax error near unexpected token `do'

I've heard of the blaunch command, which - as I understand it - will take every job and submit them under one job ID but I can't work out how to integrate it into my command without receiving the same error message. As far as I can tell, it should slot in just before the for loop.

Is anyone able to tell me where I'm going wrong with my syntax or to suggest alternative methods of batch task submission under one job ID, please?

Many thanks,

Ian

Comment: I think that `for sc in {xx..yy}` is specific to bash, not posix shell.  You might need to change `sh -c` to `bash -c`.  blaunch will help you launch a cross-host parallel job.  Since your application has an`nthreads` parameter, I assume that you want a single-host parallel job.  Put `span[hosts=1]` in the resreq to make sure all slots come from a single host.

Comment: @MichaelClosson, thank you, that did the trick! I wouldn't have thought of that! Admittedly, the program still didn't run but that's a separate issue! The tasks submitted succesfully as a single job so a big thumbs up from me!

Comment: You also might be better off running a bunch of single jobs, or a large job array.  The fairshare algorithm will charge you for 8 slots, just like 8 single jobs.  Plus, and 8 slot parallel job will be harder to schedule since 8 slots being free at the same scheduler interval is more rare than a single slot being free.

Comment: Apologies for the slow response here. Do you mean that running 8 jobs in parallel with blaunch will still result in me being charged for 8 job slots despite them being submitted as one? In that case, I agree, running individual jobs may make more sense.

Comment: That's right.  Running a single 8 slot parallel job and running 8 single jobs has the same effect on how fairshare is calculated.  You might want to consider using a job array and using the array index to control the range of `sc` values. A single job id is easier to manage.

Comment: That's true - it'd save me having to make a 'killswitch' file in case I need to stop all jobs at once! I've looked into arrays and they seem easy enough to set up so I'll give that a go on my next big batch of jobs. Thanks for the patient advice, I really appreciate it :)